# How do I use k-means on time series data that has nans?

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, cluster-analysis

I have a number of time series records that overlap at some times and don't necessarily have same start and end date. Each row represents a different time series. I made them all the same length to maintain the actual time of data collection.

For example, at t(1,2,3,4,5,6):

```
Station 1: nan, nan, 2, 4, 5, 10

Station 2: nan, 1, 4, nan, 10, 8

Station 3: 1, 9, 4, 7, nan, nan
```

I am trying to run a cluster analysis in Python to group the stations with similar behavior, where the timing of the behavior is important, so I can't just get rid of the nans. (That I know of).

Any ideas?

Comment: can you interpolate between the nan's to get a good approximation?  I am assuming that a station getting a nan is not a significant piece of information.  I.E you are not using it as something to cluster based on

Comment: @Hammer, no, you can't interpolate the values. 1st, Nan can appear anywhere, including the beginning and the tail of the time-series. 2nd, per author, the timing of the behavior is also a feature. That means when nans appear are also important. Nans are not missing values, more precisely here it means that particular trait (which can be described as integers) is not observed at that time point

Comment: @user2748977: I think it is more of a multivariate statistic problem rather than a programming problem. It appears the information in your time series are two-dimensional. First, you have a binomial response: having or not having a particular behavior. Second, in case the behavior is observed, it can be further quantified into a number. Maybe some form of multidimensional time series analysis is the most appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

K-means is not the best algorithm for this kind of data.

K-means is designed to minimize within-cluster variance (= sum of squares, WCSS).

But how do you compute variance with NaNs? And how meaningful is variance here anyway?

Instead, you may want to use

- a similarity measure designed for time series, such as DTW, threshold crossing distances etc.
- a distance based clustering algorithm. If you only have a few series, hierarchical clustering should be fine.